# Java KeyStore setEntry() using an AES SecretKey

Tags: java, encryption, aes, keystore

I'm currently working on an key-handling class in Java, specifically using a KeyStore. I'm trying to generate a SecretKey with an AES instance, then place it inside of the KeyStore using the setEntry() method.

I've included the relevant sections of my code:

```
// The KS Object
private KeyStore keyStore;

private KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry secretKeyEntry;
private KeyStore.ProtectionParameter protectionParameter;

private KeyGenerator keyGenerator;
private SecretKey secretKey, newSecretKey;


keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
keyGenerator.init(256);

newSecretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();

protectionParameter = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(KEYSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
secretKeyEntry = new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(newSecretKey);

keyStore.setEntry(KEYSTORE_ALIAS, secretKeyEntry, protectionParameter);
```

The two constants I've used are defined as Strings, too.

The Exception I keep getting is in my setEntry() call:

```
java.security.KeyStoreException: Cannot store non-PrivateKeys
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineSetKeyEntry(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineSetKeyEntry(Unknown Source)
at java.security.KeyStoreSpi.engineSetEntry(Unknown Source)
at java.security.KeyStore.setEntry(Unknown Source)
```

I'm using mainly this document http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html as a reference, along with some other sources.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: So I presume you are using a Java 7 runtime environment? Could you print out the precise version? Have you installed the unlimited crypto policy files?

Comment: How did you initialize (load) the key store? I've retrieved the same exception, but I did have to insert a specific method to load the `KeyStore` instance.

Comment: I loaded the KeyStore using a FIS or a null parameter on the .load( , KEYSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray()) method.

Comment: After fiddling on with the code and more searching, I changed the instance of the KS I was using from (KeyStore.getDefaultType()) to simply ("JCEKS"). This appears to have solved the problem.

Comment: See my answer :). Note that your *question* is more to the point, so I would not call this a dupe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6657113/589259) as a non-accepted answer on stackoverflow:

> The "Cannot store non-PrivateKeys" error message usually indicates you
>   are trying to use secret symmetric keys with a JKS keystore type. The
>   JKS keystore type only supports asymmetric (public/private) keys. You
>   would have to create a new keystore of type JCEKS to support secret
>   keys.

It is very hard to confirm this, although my memory tells me it is correct.

Comment: If you follow my solution and get an instance of a JCEKS KeyStore, it should work. The oracle example I was working from was misleading as they skipped this part out for Secret/Private Keys.

Comment: If anyone finds this using the "AndroidKeyStore" introduced in Android 4.3 it's the same deal, symmetric keys (i.e AES) are not supported Asymmetric only.

Comment: @scottyab Thanks - that's exactly the problem I'm seeing.

Comment: Note that Java 9 will switch to the **PKCS#12** (`"PKCS12"`) key store format by default. PKCS#12 key stores *should* allow `SecretKey` instances to be stored (and to be more secure to boot). This functionality should already be in Java 8 as well, but not as default. JCEKS could also be an option (as noticed in the comments below the question as well).