# How to add a owner AES key to AndroidKeyStore?

Tags: android, cryptography, aes

I want to store my AES-256 key to AndroidKeyStore, this AES-256 key is raw key (a random 32 byte). I try some code like this.

```
public foo () {
    SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] key = new byte[32];
    sr.nextBytes(key);

    try {
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        ks.load(null);

        SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("AES");
        SecretKey sk = skf.generateSecret(sks);

        ks.setEntry("key", new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(sk), new 
                KeyProtection.Builder(KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT).build());

        KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry entry = (KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry) ks.getEntry("key", null);
        SecretKey skLoad = (SecretKey) ks.getKey("key", null);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skLoad);

        Log.i(TAG, Arrays.toString(cipher.doFinal(plainBytes)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I get the exception at line SecretKey sk = skf.generateSecret(sks);

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: To generate secret key in Android Keystore, use KeyGenerator initialized with android.security.keystore.KeyGenParameterSpec
```

I know we can save key with using KeyGenerator with KeyGenParameterSpec, but I have some reason to use owner key and KeyGenParameter seem can't import my owner key. So have any idea for this problem, thank all!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28804307/android-keystore-initialization/32190055

Answer (score 2):

Generally you should not import keys from outside the key store, as they are insecure before they enter. So adding them later has limited benefits.

However, you can do a little trick: create a wrapping key in the key store and use it to wrap your symmetric key, and store the result. Then you can simply reverse the process when the key is needed again.

Unfortunately the best methods for storing keys such as (GCM-)SIV mode is generally not implemented, but hey, now you've at least heard about it.

Comment: Yeah, may be I use wrapping key. Thank you!

Comment: I wrapping the key success, and can use that key for encrypt/decrypt, but that key seem can't take out, I try KeyStore.getKey().encoded() but its take a null.