# how do I pass a predetermined value as secretkey to the keystore

Tags: java, keystore, secret-key

I have function which creates big-integer values. I want to use these values as secret-keys entries to the Keystore. I want to know if there is way of adding these Big-integer values as secret keys to the keystore. I tried to cast cast big-integer value to secret-key but it am getting an error that big-integer could not be casted to secret-key. here is the bestI have got so far.

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
char[] password = "ps".toByteArray();
ks.load(null, password);
....
BigInteger sect=getsect();
javax.crypto.SecretKey mySecretKey=(SecretKey)sect;
KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry skEntry =
    new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(mySecretKey);
ks.setEntry("secretKeyAlias", skEntry, 
    new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password));
```

since this is not working I do not know how I could add a value I wish as secretkey to the keystore. below is the error message I am getting

```
java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to javax.crypto.SecretKey
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [a tutorials](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/CreateSecretKey.htm)
- [generateSecret() api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/SecretKeyFactory.html#generateSecret%28java.security.spec.KeySpec%29)

  PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray());

  SecretKeyFactory kf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");

  SecretKey passwordKey = kf.generateSecret(keySpec);

Comment: I thank you for your answer, however although I got rid of the casting error, there is a new error: cannot store non-private-keys, although I am specifically storing secretkey.

Comment: error: java.security.KeyStoreException: cannot store non-private-keys  // it occurs when I try to setEntry() of the keystore on this code ks.setEntry("secretKeyAlias", skEntry, 
    new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password));

Comment: no idea about that error , try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656263/why-do-i-get-the-error-cannot-store-non-privatekeys-when-creating-an-ssl-socke) . Error is the same just at some different situation .

Comment: I just found source of the error here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656263/why-do-i-get-the-error-cannot-store-non-privatekeys-when-creating-an-ssl-socke